# How to define constant values of Python types defined in C++ extension with Py_LIMITED_API?

Tags: python, c++, c, python-c-api

I want to use `Py_LIMITED_API`. Thus, instead of defining my Python type statically, I define it dynamically, with specs and slots as follows.

```
struct MyType { PyObject_HEAD };

static void MyType_dealloc( MyType * self ) { PyObject_DEL( self ); }

static PyObject * MyType_new( PyTypeObject * type, PyObject * args, PyObject * kwds ) {
    return (PyObject *)PyObject_NEW( MyType, type );
}

static int MyType_init( MyType * self, PyObject * args, PyObject * kwds ) { return 0; }

static PyType_Slot MyType_slots[] = {
    { Py_tp_doc, (void *)PyDoc_STR("MyType objects") },
    { Py_tp_dealloc, (void *)&MyType_dealloc },
    { Py_tp_init, (void *)&MyType_init },
    { Py_tp_new, (void *)&MyType_new },
    { 0, NULL }
};

static PyType_Spec MyType_spec = {
    "MyType",
    sizeof(MyType),
    0,
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE,
    MyType_slots
};

static PyTypeObject * MyTypePtr = NULL;

static PyModuleDef MyModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "MyModule",
    "My C++ Module.",
    -1,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_MyModule(void)
{
    PyObject* m = PyModule_Create( &MyModule );
    if (m == NULL) return NULL;
    MyTypePtr = (PyTypeObject*)PyType_FromSpec( &MyType_spec );
    if ( MyTypePtr == NULL ) return NULL;
    if ( PyType_Ready( MyTypePtr ) < 0 ) return NULL;
    PyDict_SetItemString( MyTypePtr->tp_dict, "Normal", PyLong_FromLong( 0 ) );
    PyDict_SetItemString( MyTypePtr->tp_dict, "Custom", PyLong_FromLong( 15 ) );
    Py_INCREF( MyTypePtr );
    PyModule_AddObject( m, "MyType", (PyObject *)MyTypePtr );
    return m;
}
```

With this definition of my module, I can write the following.

```
from MyModule import *
print( MyType.Normal )
print( MyType.Custom )
```

My problem is that with `Py_LIMITED_API`, I cannot use `tp_dict` to define the constant values `Normal` and `Custom`.

I've tried to use `PyType_GetSlot`, but `Py_tp_dict` does not exist. (I guess I understand why: it's because it would allow modifications of existing types.)

Now my question is: In the code above with specs and slots, how can I define the constants `Normal` and `Custom` of the type `MyType` without using `tp_dict`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Thanks, but `PyModule_AddIntConstant` is meant to define the constant value for the module. I want to assign the constant value to the type `MyType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very simple answer: call `PyObject_SetAttrString` on the type object.

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_MyModule(void)
{
    PyObject* m = PyModule_Create( &MyModule );
    if (m == NULL) return NULL;
    MyTypePtr = (PyTypeObject*)PyType_FromSpec( &MyType_spec );
    if ( MyTypePtr == NULL ) return NULL;
    if ( PyType_Ready( MyTypePtr ) < 0 ) return NULL;
    PyObject_SetAttrString( (PyObject*)MyTypePtr, "Normal", PyLong_FromLong( 0 ) );
    PyObject_SetAttrString( (PyObject*)MyTypePtr, "Custom", PyLong_FromLong( 15 ) );
    Py_INCREF( MyTypePtr );
    PyModule_AddObject( m, "MyType", (PyObject *)MyTypePtr );
    return m;
}
```

Guess it also works with `PyObject_SetAttr`.

No more use of `tp_dict`.

Can enable `Py_LIMITED_API` with this.